# pegar numero de resultados de uma consulta com o banco usando o cakephp

Tags: cakephp, query

Quero fazer um loop para mostrar os resultados de uma consulta do banco de dados, e pegar o numero de resultados encontrados na consulta. Estou usando o cakephp.
Ele tem alguma função que faça a mesma coisa que o **mysqli_num_rows**?

Comment: Essa pergunta tem uma resposta aceita e confirmada na pergunta [Como contar quantas linhas uma consulta ao banco de dados retornou (Cake PHP)?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44884/como-contar-quantas-linhas-uma-consulta-ao-banco-de-dados-retornou-cake-php).

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o "count()" do objeto ResultSet

http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.ResultSet.html

Comment: Olá old7, esse link pode fornecer uma resposta para pergunta mas um dia ele pode a vir ficar offline, ou o endereço trocar, e assim a resposta ficará inútil. O melhor seria você postar o procedimento aqui.

Comment: Basicamente é chamar o metodo count no resultado da query: $result->count(); O link se refere a documentação do Cake PHP