# Como contar quantas linhas uma consulta ao banco de dados retornou (Cake PHP)?

Tags: query, cakephp-2

```
$this->Post->Comment->find
    ('all', array('conditions' => array('Comment.post_id' => $id)));
```

Faço essa consulta, como saber se retornou 5, 7, 10... comentários antes de exibí-los na view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponho que você esteja guardando o resultado numa variável, certo? Algo assim:

```
$comentarios = $this->Post->Comment->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Comment.post_id' => $id)));
```

Nesse caso, use a função `count` do php para obter a quantidade:

```
$quantidade = count($comentarios);
```

Comment: Isso mesmo. Valeu cara!

Answer (score 1):

Use o `find('count');`

```
$count = $this->Post->Comment->find
    ('count', array('conditions' => array('Comment.post_id' => $id)));
```

Comment: Valeu! Mas no caso preciso dos dados da consulta também!

Comment: @IWannaKnow soh para deixar arquivado, voce pode usar os dois, tanto o 'count' quanto o 'all'

Comment: Ao mesmo tempo? find('count', 'all'...  ?

Comment: @IWannaKnow um de cada vez hehe

Comment: Então, eu faço a consulta e a aproveito usando o 'count' como o @bfaveretto colocou. Mas obrigado mais uma vez.